# Trying to copy a 2D dimensional array of objects to another function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to copy an array from one class to to another class by passing it to a function but I'm running into issues. The array that I'm trying to copy seems to lose all its data.

```
// A.h

class A
public:
virtual void Test();
private:
A* array2D[30][32];
```

```
// A.cpp

void A::Test()
{
    B* f = new B();
    f->pass(array2D);
}
```

```
// B.h

class A;
class B
{
public:
void pass(A *a[][32]);

private: 
A *a[30][32];
}
```

```
// B.cpp

void B::pass(A *array2D[][32])
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j <= 32; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = array2D[i][j];

        }

    }
}
```

My guess is that it's happening when I'm passing it but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `A* array2D[30][32];` -- A two dimensional array of pointers?  Is this really the intention?

Comment: `a[i][j] = a[i][j];` that seems pretty strange

Comment: Oh i meant to say an array of objects let me fix that sorry about that

Comment: was typing to fast and messed up what i was trying to describe sorry again

Comment: Pretend there were no classes, and you just had two 2-d arrays.  You don't need a hand-coded `for` loop to copy from one to the other.  I think your function `pass` just convolutes the whole idea.

Comment: Still, `A* array2D[30][32]` is a 2D array of pointers. Your `pass` function is assigning pointers not copying the objects where they eventually point to.

Comment: I think this slowly turning into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  First, a 2D array copy can be done in 1 line of code using `std::copy` and providing the proper arguments -- no need for a nested `for` loop.  But as @anastaciu points out, what is your real intent here?  Is is to copy objects, not pointers?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)` -- This is a memory overwrite on the last iteration of the loop.  There is no row `30` for an `array[30][32]`.  The same goes for the columns, as you're going out-of-bounds there too.  Using `<=` in a `for` loop is a red flag.

Comment: @paulMcKenzie yeah i want to try to copy it without Std::copy i honestly dont really like using Std libraries unless i dont have a choice. And Yes i want to copy the whole array to another array in another class

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so pretty much i want lets say array2D1[32]30] = array2D[32][30] by passing over through a function

Comment: `std::copy` is an algorithm function.  What is your reason for not using those functions?  It isn't a container -- it is basically no different than if you used `strcpy`, `memset`, or some other function from the `C` library, except that `std::copy` knows C++.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that it's happening when I'm passing it but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

First, your `for` loops to populate the array go out-of-bounds on the last iteration of the nested `for` loop:

```
void B::pass(A *array2D[][32])
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)  // This goes out-of-bounds on the last iteration
    {
       for (int j = 0; j <= 32; j++)  // This also goes out-of-bounds.
        {
            a[i][j] = array2D[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Using `<=` in a `for` loop is an indication that things can go wrong, and they do go wrong with your code.  The fix would simply be:

```
void B::pass(A *array2D[][32])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = array2D[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

This will work, however it is inefficient (unless a great optimizing compiler sees that this is inefficient and changes the code).

---

The better way to do this is a simple call to `std::copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>

void B::pass(A *array2D[][32])
{
    std::copy(&array2D[0][0], &array2D[29][32], &a[0][0]);
}
```

The reason why this works is that two-dimensional arrays in C++ have their data layout in contiguous memory, thus it is essentially a one-dimensional array.  So giving the starting and ending address of the array elements is all that's required.

A compiler will more than likely see that you are copying a trivially-copyable type (a pointer), thus the call to `std::copy` results in a call to `memcpy`.